# making a menu that pops out of screen right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a bootstrap site, and want to make a sort of pop out menu from the right of the screen. This menu needs to be hidden' and when a button "Menu" is clicked it pops out of screen right, and **covers** whatever is on screen right. it does not **push** the content out of the way. Kind of like the windows 8 menu when you slide your finger from screen right.

I've thought of making a dropdown menu, since it behaves almost like I want, except for it's position. But I need to change the dropdown behaviour, So that instead of the dropdown menu popping out attached to the dropdown button, it pops out of screen right, but I can't find out how to do this.

```
<head>
    ...
    <link href ="CSS/Bootstrap.min.css" rel ="stylesheet"/>        
</head> 
<div class="col-xs-3">
    <!--some side content-->
</div>
<div class="col-xs-9">
    <!--some side content-->
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <li class="dropup">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu
                    <ul> class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </a>
            </li>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
<script src="JS/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="JS/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I have three folders in my project:

1. Css with bootstrap css files(bootstrap-theme, bootstrap-theme min, bootstrap, bootstrap min)
2. Fonts
3. JS with bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js

Please show me how to do this.

If you know of a different way of making the menu I want in bootstrap I'd love to hear it as well.

Comment: Check out [Simple Sidebar](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/)

Comment: @Mi-Creativity, I mean without using  a drop-down, like what I thought of doing, but still in bootstrap.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda, that kind of menu is not what I want. It pushes other content out of the way when it opens. I want the menu to **cover** the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example to get you going:

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/nq7db6L7/)</kbd>

Note that an `id` was added to the `a` tag that opens the menu, to make it easy for jQuery to capture the click event on that element.

In the jQuery, we are using a variable `mnuOut` to keep track of whether the menu is IN or OUT (visible or hidden).

Also, we use the `.animate()` method to animate the slide out from the right. This works by changing the css attribute `right`:

FROM `right:-80px` (slid 80px beyond the right side of the screen)

TO `right:0` where the right-most edge of the myMenu DIV is flush against the right side of the screen.

---

**HTML:**

```
<div id="myMenu">
  <div id="item1" class="submenu">Item 1</div>
  <div id="item2" class="submenu">Item 2</div>
  <div id="item3" class="submenu">Item 3</div>
</div>

<a id="menuTrigger" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu
```

**CSS:**

```
#myMenu{position:fixed;top:20px;right:-80px;width:80px;height:300px;background:palegreen;}
.submenu{width:100%;height:20px;padding:20px 5px;border:1px solid green;}
#menuTrigger:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
mnuOut=false;

$('#menuTrigger').click(function(){
  if (mnuOut){
        //Menu is visible, so HIDE menu
      $('#myMenu').animate({
        right: '-80px'
      },800);
      mnuOut = false;
  }else{
        //Menu is hidden, so SHOW menu
      $('#myMenu').animate({
        right: 0
      },800);
      mnuOut = true;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, It works perfectly! - except one thing. I need the size to be flexible, like bootstrap col-xs etc. classes. I tried putting the menu inside a div with class col-xs-2, and in CSS : #myMenu{...width: 100%...} but then the menu opens on the whole screen , instead of just filling the div. Also: How can I make the menu the same height as the screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your menu to cover the content make sure you add

```
position: absolute;
```

Or

```
position: fixed;
```

Then after that give it

```
right: 500px;
```

But instead of 500px use the width of your menu
And to make it popout just override the

```
right: 0;
```

Making it 0 will make it stick to the right back to its original position

Answer (score 1):

What you want requires a little more than just a couple of lines of css but I think this will give you a good start. Just style according to your theme:

HTML

```
<div id="oneout">
  <span class="onetitle">
    menu
</span>
  <div id="oneout_inner">
    <center>
      menu info here
      <br>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #oneout {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    right: 1px;
    width: 18px;
    padding: 40px 0;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
  }

  #oneout_inner {
    top: 60px;
    right: -250px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    text-align: left;
    border:1px solid #333;
  }

  #oneout:hover {
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 250px;
  }

  #oneout:hover #oneout_inner {
    z-index: 1000;
    right: 0px;
  }

  .onetitle {
    display: block;
    writing-mode: lr-tb;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    position: absolute;
    right: -11px;
    top: 3px;
    font-family: Lucida Sans;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
  }
```

Here is a working [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQLKWV)